# How to integrate IP cycling into my webscraping program? I keep getting blocked from Crunchbase

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, ip

I wrote a program that uses Beautiful Soup to extract funding information from Crunchbase for a list of companies and export that information in a CSV file. I even spaced out my requests by 30 seconds, and the program was working fine until today - now I can't even send one request without getting an HTTPError: Forbidden.

I've been reading up on this and people have made IP cycling programs, because it looks like Crunchbase has been blocking my IP address - even if I cycle my User Agent, I still get blocked. I even tried using a couple of free VPNs, but I still get blocked.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import random

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 
Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent, }

def scraper(url):
    return_list = []

    try:
        request = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    except:
        return_list.append("No Crunchbase Page Found")
        return_list.append("No Crunchbase Page Found")
        print("Not found")
    else:
        data = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

        try:
            funding_status = soup.find_all("span", class_= "component--field-formatter field-type-enum ng-star-inserted")[1].text
            return_list.append(funding_status)
        except:
            return_list.append("N/A")

        try:
            last_funding_type = soup.find("a", class_= "cb-link component--field-formatter field-type-enum ng-star-inserted").text
            if last_funding_type[:6] != "Series" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Venture" and last_funding_type[:4] != "Seed" and last_funding_type[:3] != "Pre" and last_funding_type[:5] != "Angel" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Private" and last_funding_type[:4] != "Debt" and last_funding_type[:11] != "Convertible" and last_funding_type[:5] != "Grant" and last_funding_type[:9] != "Corporate" and last_funding_type[:6] != "Equity" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Product" and last_funding_type[:9] != "Secondary" and last_funding_type[:4] != "Post" and last_funding_type[:3] != "Non" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Initial" and last_funding_type[:7] != "Funding":
                return_list.append("N/A")
            else:
                return_list.append(last_funding_type)
        except:
            return_list.append("N/A")

    return return_list


user_input = input("CSV File Name (e.g: myfile.csv): ")
user_input2 = input("New CSV file name (e.g: newfile.csv): ")
print()
scrape_file = open(user_input, "r", newline = '', encoding = "utf-8")
row_count = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(scrape_file))
scrape_file = open(user_input, "r", newline = '', encoding = "utf-8")

new_file = open(user_input2, "w", newline = '', encoding = "utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(new_file)
writer.writerow(["Company Name", "Description", "Website", "Founded", 
"Product Name", "Country", "Funding Status", "Last Funding Type"])

count = 0
for row in csv.reader(scrape_file):
    company_name = row[0]
    if company_name == "Company Name":
        continue

    count += 1
    print("Scraping company {} of {}".format(count, row_count))

    company_name = company_name.replace(",", "")
    company_name = company_name.replace("'", "")
    company_name = company_name.replace("-", " ")
    company_name = company_name.replace(".", " ")
    s = "-"
    join_name = s.join(company_name.lower().split())
    company_url = "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/" + join_name

    writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], scraper(company_url)[0], scraper(company_url)[1]])
    time.sleep(random.randint(30, 40))
new_file.close()
print("Done! You can now open your file %s." % user_input2)
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction for how to integrate IP cycling in this project so that it sends requests from different IP addresses! I'm not looking to pay for private proxies, but I've seen people do it with public addresses. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as correct or comment why it was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to receive a response you need to have some kind of proxy, your own like squidproxy, paid private proxy or public (or VPN as you mentioned). There is no way around it. You can spoof your IP in the packet you send to some false IP but then you will not receive a response. If you wish to use a proxy I would suggest going with excellent `requests` library as it is a tool of choice for many people doing web scraping and using a proxy with it is just extremely easy. Example follows:

```
import requests
proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128', #this could be an public proxy address
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}
requests.get("https://www.google.com",proxies=proxies)
```

and if you wish to cycle through a list of public proxies just loop through it handling exceptions like so:

```
import requests
import logging
proxies = [{
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128', #this could be an public proxy address
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
},...]

for proxy in proxies:
    try:
        requests.get("https://www.google.com",proxies=proxies)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        continue
```